# Solve indefinite integral $\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I multiply the integral so that I can get $-x^2$ in the numerator. I then expand the fraction so I can split the integral into easier integrals.

$$-\int\frac{-x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

$$-\int\frac{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}-1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

$$-\int 1 dx
-\int\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

$$-\int 1 dx
+\int\frac{1}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
+\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

I then tried to do the same thing with one of the other integrals I got out of this (the fatal flaw).

$$-\int 1 dx
+\int\frac{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}+x^2-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
+\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

$$-\int 1 dx
+\int 1 dx
+\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
-\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Then some integrals cancel out and all that remains is:
$$\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

The problem is that this the original integral and I can't think of another way to approach this.

Could someone point out the thing I'm missing? This problem can't be solved with per partes or substitution as I can see.

Comment: It seems that you added zero to your original integral, basically doing nothing to it.

Comment: That seems to be the case... But maybe I can try rationalizing the denominator and go from there? I forgot to do the most obvious thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ motivates us to use change of variable by trigonometric functions. The term $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ naturally implies $x\in[-1,1]$ and so we can assume $x=\sin(t)$, $t\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^2}{1-x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx&=\int\frac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)+\cos(t)}\,\cos(t)\,dt\\
&=\int\frac{1-\cos^2(t)}{1+\cos(t)}\,dt\\
&=\int\left(1-\cos(t)\right)\,dt\\
&=t-\sin(t)+C\\
&=\arcsin(x)-x+C.
\end{align*}